# Tracking who done what; mongo Atomicity when deleting by filter

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I've been implementing an auditing system for mongo that tracks call and user information for each mongo transaction. 
IE user bill 
made a call to x endpoint 
at y time 
and changed z field from foo to bar

inserts and updates are easy because I tie a stored call info object to any objects updated in that call. (through a set property or updating the property directly on a replace or upsert call.)

all that works great.

Deletes are a hairy beast though.

when I delete by id I can easily track that information. BUT when I delete by filter

IE delete from users where username like bill.

mongo doesn't return the deleted ids back in the response. if I query to get those objects before I delete them who knows what could happen between the time I get those objects and when I actually delete them.

(Knock Knock, race condition. who's there?)

any ideas on how to keep the atomicity of that delete and have a reliable way to tie that delete call to the delete transaction?